# Getting data from database with mysql and php - special characters

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, chart.js

I followed this tutorial: [how to draw bar graph using data from mysql table](https://www.dyclassroom.com/chartjs/chartjs-how-to-draw-bar-graph-using-data-from-mysql-table-and-php)

It was working fine until a special character appear for example `azúcar`. I tried to change it to `azucar` but the rows of my table are full of weird characters like `something /s something` so when it encounters something like that the `data.php` just go blank

I tried doing these two possible solutions:

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
```

and

```
json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

but none of them worked

Comment: it sounds like your data may be stored in latin1 vs utf8; in which case, there may not be a real solution, other than re-importing your data into a utf8 ready table.

Comment: i tried, my database and my table are in utf8_general_ci instead of latin1, and still not working

Comment: as you had stated; `the rows of my table are full of weird characters`, then that means the data is corrupted; either on importing, or on changing the collation/field types. please note, you cannot just change table/field collation and have it automatically "fix" imported data; in most cases that will mess your data up.

Comment: I dont think is corrupted in that way, since i from chile and we speak spanish we have accent mark and something like this "pechuga s/ hueso" means "chicken breast without bone" im getting the data from scrapping a web site